# Empty post title Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

is there a way to check if post title is empty and then and if post title is empty automatically set that post to draft or hide on frontend? I know there is a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-title-validation/
but from me is not option.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Like:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [wp_insert_post_data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) filter can do that:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );
function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    // Change post status if empty post title
    if( empty($data['post_title']) ) {
      $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that typing `</>` works too.